# Images no show on Blazor

Tags: blazor-webassembly

Any one please can help me to see why not show it the images

```
<img src="~/images/Loading.gif" alt="Loading" />
```

Images

[image: 1]

well it suppose that have to show the images but not working

Answer (score 1):

The tilde (~) is interpreted by Asp.Net component, but as this is a native html img element, just remove the tilde and leading slash:

```
<img src = "images/Loading.gif" alt ="Loading" />
```